# Serving two websites with Apache with single domain name and single IP address

Tags: apache

I am trying to host two websites using Apache from the same Ubuntu server.  I have one ip address, and I only have one domain (which resolves to the ip address).  So I want requests to the domain name to give one website, and requests to the ip address to give the other.

I have symlinks in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled to two files, pointing to the config for my two sites.

One contains:

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
    ServerName 1.2.3.4
    stuff
</VirtualHost>
```

while the other contains

```
<VirtualHost domain.net:80>
    ServerName domain.net
    stuff
</VirtualHost>
```

However, when I start Apache, I get the following message:

```
[warn] VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80 overlaps with VirtualHost domain.net:80, the first has precedence, perhaps you need a NameVirtualHost directive
```

and when I point my browser at either domain.net or 1.2.3.4 I get the site that I want associated with the ip address.

If I delete either symlink, then pointing a browser at either the domain name or the ip address gives the only enabled website.  (As you would hope.)

As I understand it, both config files in sites-enabled are being loaded at once, and the one containing the ip address trumps the one containing the domain name.  The warning suggests looking at the NameVirtualHost directive, but all the help I can find online refers to cases where you have two domain names pointing to the same ip address.

As always, and help or advice would be much appreciated.

(For what it's worth, the websites are both Rails applications, and I'm deploying using Passenger, but I don't think that's important here.)

Comment: FYI, questions like these are best served on serverfault.com

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is how I do it:

```
NameVirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80

<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/default
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
    ServerName mydomain.net
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache looks for a suitable virtualhost for every request. If it doesn't find one that matches the `ServerName` or any of the `ServerAliases` then it takes the first one. It doesn't really matter what you use for the `ServerName` in the first `VirtualHost` as it will always be used if none of the other `VirtualHosts` match.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! I 've been trying to find out how to stop Apache from serving random content when someone does an IP request and now I know. :)

Comment: So you used one virtualhost file for the 2 domains ?

Answer (score 4):

Had this problem, here is what I did:

Edit httpd.conf

```
sudo vi /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

Add this line

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

NOTE: You can replace ***:80** with **your_ip_address:80**

Now create the domain name config file. I use the domain_name.com

```
sudo vi /etc/apache2/sites-available/domain.com
```

Add this to the file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
     ServerName www.domain.com
     ServerAlias domain.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/public_html/
     ErrorLog /var/www/domain.com/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /var/www/domain.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Make sure the directories in the domain.com config exists

```
/var/www/domain.com/public_html/
/var/www/domain.com/logs
```

NOTE: use the mkdir command like this if needed

```
sudo mkdir /var/www/domain.com/public_html/
sudo mkdir /var/www/domain.com/logs
```

Now we need to enable the new config file like this

```
sudo a2ensite domain.com
```

You should see a notice to restart apache, use this command

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Now we need a test file to view

```
sudo vi /var/www/domain.com/public_html/index.html
```

Add some text

```
Hello domain.com
```

Open your web browser and go to your new domain

```
http://domain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the instruction

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

in /etc/apache2/ports.conf